# Gradle : can i use the scala plugin for an application written only in java?

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I am new to gradle and i have an application written in Java that i want to migrate to the Scala language; not all the code but just some classes; especially the main class (the endpoint of the application)

So the first thing i did was to add the scala plugin in the build.gradle file, to add the scala librairy to dependencies and to change the name of the folder where Java source code were located from "src/.../java" to "src/.../scala".

without even adding a scala code (even if this is the next step), the project no longer runs. The output of the run command is :

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
> Cannot invoke method withInputStream() on null object
```

So that is why i'm asking if it's possible to use the scala plugin or the scala compilator in a gradle project for an application written only in  Java.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. The Java files should remain in `java` folders. 2. If the build still fails, try adding a dummy Scala class.

Comment: Thanks. I left the java files in the `java` folder and it worked. But i still don't know how to add scala files in the project. 
Please any idea ?

Comment: Just put them into `src/main/scala` (and `src/test/scala` for tests).